# Explaination of double vertical bar in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Can anyone explain me, what does mean this double vertical bar "||"  in this code, which is from oracle ApEx. Thanks for response.

Code:

```
DECLARE
l_f01 VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f01.count
   LOOP
      l_f01 := l_f01 || apex_application.g_f01(i) ||',';
   END LOOP;
   l_f01 := rtrim(l_f01, ',');

   htp.p('P18_EMPNO: ' || :P18_EMPNO || 
         ' - X01: '    || apex_application.g_x01 || 
         ' - F01: '    || l_f01 );
END;
```

Comment: String concatenation ... see documentation

Comment: [The documentation for this can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators003.htm#SQLRF51156). Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks much for fast response

Answer (score 0):

The double vertical bars, ||, are the sql concatenation operator, it combines strings.  For example: `'he' || 'llo'` is the same thing as `'hello'`.